Iterate through objects without array
I've got JSON data that looks like this (notice that it's a list of individual objects without wrapping by []). I would like to walk each object using jq but it is not an array of objects. So how can I walk to each object without fixing the data to be a valid array of objects?
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
{
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4
}


jq -s will present the stream of objects as a single array.

Use inputs in combination with the --null-input (or -n) flag. It will provide an iteration of all inputs. Accordingly, the singular input will fetch one input on evaluation. The --null-input (or -n) flag is necessary as the context . would have already consumed the first input when reaching input or inputs, which then starts fetching starting from the second input. With --null-input (or -n) set, the context . is bound to null, so input and inputs get all the inputs available.
Example 1:
jq -n 'inputs | keys'

[
  "a",
  "b"
]
[
  "c",
  "d"
]

Demo
Example 2:
jq -n '{head: input, tail: [inputs]}'

{
  "head": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  "tail": [
    {
      "c": 3,
      "d": 4
    }
  ]
}

Demo
Note that for cases like the latter example, where the first input is treated individually, you can revert to using . for that first input. jq '{head: ., tail: [inputs]}' (without -n) yields the same result (Demo).

from your example, I actually can do this [inputs] which wrap objects under array. Thanks for your tips of using inputs

@Nam Sure, by using -n, you start out with a single context, which you can use the array generator in, to produce exactly one array. Therein, inputs expands to as many inputs as there are. On the contrary, inputs | [.] would first expand to a multitude of contexts, and then create an array for each one of them.
